# C++ segmentation fault when creating pthreads

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, pthreads

```
void createThreads(int k){
struct threadData threadData[k];

int numThreads = k;
int i = 0;
int err = 0;

pthread_t *threads = static_cast<pthread_t*>(malloc(sizeof(pthread_t) * numThreads));
for(i = 0;i<numThreads;i++){

    threadData[i].thread_id = i;
    threadData[i].startIndex = ((N/k)*i);
    threadData[i].stopIndex = ((N/k)*(i+1));

    err = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, foo, (void *)&threadData[i]);


    if(err != 0){
        printf("error creating thread\n");
    }
}
}
```

Here, N and k are integers where the remainder of N/k is guaranteed to be 0.
including createThreads(numThreads); in main will cause my program to seg fault and commenting it out will take care of this however any printf debug statements I put into createThreads (even on the first line inside the function) will not show so I am pretty confused as to how to debug this. All help is appreciated.

Comment: It's not the cause of your problem, but why are you using malloc in C++?

Comment: `struct threadData threadData[k];`  This is not legal C++.  You can't create an array using a variable as the number of entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose the problem is that your arg parameter is on stack of your createThreads function:

> struct threadData threadData[k];

so once your thread gets created and run, and createThreads returns, threadData is no longer valid, so your thread function should not touch argument data. Otherwise its undefinded behaviour and crash.

so to fix it, you should either, make threadData global (outside createThreads), or malloc it.

Comment: This is definitely a problem. But there can also be further problems in `foo` itself.